# I get this error when printing pdf in django, the error states like this module "'urllib.request' has no attribute 'splithost'"

Tags: python, django

I want to print/display pdf from html file in django. I did what I could but i ended up getting an error which i struggled to resolve but couldn't. I need help in resolving this. It states like this
" **'urllib.request' has no attribute 'splithost'** "

My url pattern

```
path('pdf/<int:id>/', views.pdf.as_view(), name='pdf')
```

The views.py is like this:

```
class pdf(View):
def get(self, request, id):
    try:
        single_record = get_object_or_404(sales, id = id)
        selling_price = single_record.sales_name.selling_price_per_each * single_record.quantity
    except:
        Http404('Content Not Found')
    context = {
        'sales': single_record,
        'total_amount': selling_price
    }
    sales_pdf = renderPdf('istock/pdf.html', context)
    response = HttpResponse(sales_pdf, content_type = 'application/pdf')
    return response
```

The resources (resources.py) file included in views looks like this:

```
from import_export import resources
from .models import sales

class salesResource(resources.ModelResource):
   class Meta:
      model = sales
```

Also the require.py file looks like this:

```
from io import BytesIO
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template.loader import get_template
from xhtml2pdf import pisa


def renderPdf(template, context = {}):
    t = get_template(template)
    send_data = t.render(context)
    result = BytesIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(send_data.encode("ISO-8859-1")), result)
    if not pdf.err:
        return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type = 'application/pdf')
    else:
        return None
```

and the html file (pdf.html) looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  {% load staticfiles %}
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>{{sales.sales_name.product_name}} PDF</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/w3.css' %}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'style.css' %}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/all.min.css' %}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet'>
  <style>
  table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
  }

  td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
  }

  tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="outer-container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="contents">
        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
          <div class=" w3-card">
            <div class="btn-head">
                <h3>{{sales.sales_name.product_name}} Details</h3>
            <table >
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>Sales Number</td>
                  <td>{{sales.id}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Product Manufacturer</td>
                  <td>{{sales.sales_name.manufacturer}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td> Date Sold</td>
                  <td>{{sales.date_of_sale | date:"F d Y"}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Sales Quantity</td>
                  <td>{{sales.quantity}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Sales Price per each</td>
                  <td>{{sales.sales_name.selling_price_per_each}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Total Sales Amount</td>
                  <td>{{total_amount}}</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

The whole traceback is like this:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/pdf/12/

Django Version: 2.2.7
Python Version: 3.8.0
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'istock_app',
'crispy_forms',
'import_export']
Installed Middleware:
 ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



  Traceback:

   File "C:\Users\JONASS~1\DJANGO~1\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
   34.             response = get_response(request)

   File "C:\Users\JONASS~1\DJANGO~1\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
   115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

  File "C:\Users\JONASS~1\DJANGO~1\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\JONASS~1\DJANGO~1\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\JONASS~1\DJANGO~1\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  97.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "E:\dProjects\istock\istock_app\views.py" in get
  240.         sales_pdf = renderPdf('istock/pdf.html', context)

File "E:\dProjects\istock\istock_app\require.py" in renderPdf
 11.     pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(send_data.encode("ISO-8859-1")), result)

File "C:\Users\JONASS~1\DJANGO~1\lib\site-packages\xhtml2pdf\document.py" in pisaDocument
  96.     context = pisaStory(src, path, link_callback, debug, default_css, xhtml,

File "C:\Users\JONASS~1\DJANGO~1\lib\site-packages\xhtml2pdf\document.py" in pisaStory
  59.     pisaParser(src, context, default_css, xhtml, encoding, xml_output)

File "C:\Users\JONASS~1\DJANGO~1\lib\site-packages\xhtml2pdf\parser.py" in pisaParser   
 753.     context.parseCSS()

File "C:\Users\JONASS~1\DJANGO~1\lib\site-packages\xhtml2pdf\context.py" in parseCSS
  500.         self.css = self.cssParser.parse(self.cssText)

   File "C:\Users\JONASS~1\DJANGO~1\lib\site-packages\xhtml2pdf\w3c\cssParser.py" in parse
   450.                 src, stylesheet = self._parseStylesheet(src)

 File "C:\Users\JONASS~1\DJANGO~1\lib\site-packages\xhtml2pdf\w3c\cssParser.py" in _parseStylesheet
  541.         src, stylesheetImports = self._parseAtImports(src)

  File "C:\Users\JONASS~1\DJANGO~1\lib\site-packages\xhtml2pdf\w3c\cssParser.py" in _parseAtImports
   625.             stylesheet = self.cssBuilder.atImport(import_, mediums, self)

 File "C:\Users\JONASS~1\DJANGO~1\lib\site-packages\xhtml2pdf\w3c\css.py" in atImport
  909.             return cssParser.parseExternal(import_)

  File "C:\Users\JONASS~1\DJANGO~1\lib\site-packages\xhtml2pdf\context.py" in  parseExternal
  394.         cssFile = self.c.getFile(cssResourceName, relative=self.rootPath)

  File "C:\Users\JONASS~1\DJANGO~1\lib\site-packages\xhtml2pdf\context.py" in getFile
  818.         return getFile(name, relative or self.pathDirectory)

  File "C:\Users\JONASS~1\DJANGO~1\lib\site-packages\xhtml2pdf\util.py" in     getFile
  738.     file = pisaFileObject(*a, **kw)

 File "C:\Users\JONASS~1\DJANGO~1\lib\site-packages\xhtml2pdf\util.py" in   __init__ 
  639.                 server, path =    urllib2.splithost(uri[uri.find("//"):])

Exception Type: AttributeError at /pdf/12/
Exception Value: module 'urllib.request' has no attribute 'splithost'
```

Comment: This code does not call `splithost()`.  Please post the entire error traceback message.

Comment: I have already edited the question you can now see to what extent i have messed around

Comment: You are running Python 3 but your xhtml2pdf package is for Python 2.

Comment: What can i do as i tried to upgrade it and i failed?

Answer (score 1):

Use xhtml2pdf version 0.2.5 (latest version as of today) instead of 0.2.3.

As state in [here](https://github.com/xhtml2pdf/xhtml2pdf/issues/456), python 3.8 removed splithost from urllib.request, which caused a bug in xhtml2pdf version 0.2.3, which uses urllib.request.splithost

Comment: Please add some context to your answer i.e. What's the real problem in the earlier version and what's new added in the new version to sort this out. Single liners can help today but not in the future.

Comment: just added more context